# Angularjs passing parameter to a page from ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have following three buttons on top of my page with input box underneath it.

```
<div>
  <form>
          <div>
              Enter Show Name<input type="text" ng-model="showName" />
          </div>
      </form>
</div>
<div>
<button ng-click="href="/api/renameShow"">Rename Show</button>
<button ng-click="href="/api/updateShow"">Update  Show</button>
<button ng-click="href="/api/checkShow"">Check   Show</button>
</div>
```

My module code with routes is

```
    var showApp = angular.module("showApp", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "ui"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/',
            {
                controller: '',
                templateUrl: 'main.html'
            }).
            when('/api/renameShow', { controller: 'renameShowCtrl', templateUrl:     '/templates/renameShow.html' }).
            when('/api/updateShow', { controller: 'updateShowCtrl', templateUrl:     '/templates/updateShow.html' }).
when('/api/checkShow', { controller: 'checkShowCtrl', templateUrl: '/templates/checkShow.html' });
```

Basically what I am trying to do is that when one of the buttons is clicked the ng-click  calls the corrosponding page passing the parameter "showName" with it.
Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: is there any specfic reason to use button you can instead use an anchor href="/api/checkShow/{{showName}}" and in routing handle it with /api/checkShow/:id

Comment: So it would be like this in routing?    when('/api/checkShow/:id', { controller: 'checkShowCtrl', templateUrl: '/templates/checkShow.html' })

Comment: yep you can refer this http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: @J.Davidson, Vinod has said it correct, do not use button for page forwarding, you can use anchor tag, if you want button mandatory menas then use ng-click following a function, there in you can use location.url('/api/checkShow/'+id); Better use anchor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all you need to tell your destination controllers (the page you are referring to) to expect and accept a parameter when we navigate to that page:

```
$routeProvider.when('/api/renameShow/:showName?', { 
  controller: 'renameShowCtrl', 
  templateUrl:     '/templates/renameShow.html' 
})
```

The question mark after the parameter denotes that it's an optional parameter. You can achieve the same with anchor tags:

`<a href="#/view2/mike">Go to view 2</a>`

If you insist on using buttons, write a custom function hooking onto the ng-click of the button, and then pass whatever parameter you want like this from your current controller:

```
<button ng-click="customNavigate('Mike')">Rename Show</button>
```

And in the controller:

```
    $scope.customNavigate=function(msg){
       $location.path("/view2"+msg)
    }
```

and then in the destination controller:

```
app.controller("renameShowCtrl",function($scope,$routeParams){
   $scope.showName=$routeParams.showName
});
```

Comment: I Think you missed a slash in the path : $scope.customNavigate=function(msg){
       $location.path("/view2/"+msg)
    }

Comment: Otherwise great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Say we need psoid in sodtl.htm:

In HTML - so.html:

```
<tr ng-controller="SoController" ng-repeat="x in sos">
            <td>{{x.date}}</td>
            <td><a href="#/sodtl/{{x.soid}}">Dtl</a></td>
</tr>
```

In AngularJs - app.js - Config:

```
 app.config(function ($routeProvider)
    {    
        $routeProvider.
        when ('/sodtl/:psoid?',
                {
                    templateUrl : 'pages/sodtl.html',
                    controller  : 'SoDtlController'
                }
              )
    });
```

In Controller - app.js:

```
app.controller('SoDtlController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.message = " $routeParams.psoid = " + $routeParams.psoid;
});
```

Thus you can use psoid in showing data in sodtl.html page.